# The type or namespace User cannot be found

Tags: c#, .net

Here is my code, I have searched high and low for a whole day, but I am a new programmer so the answer is probably right in front of me, maybe new eyes can see it. Debug error is:

> The type or namespace User Cannot be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference)

My code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace verifyUsers
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            parser userParser = new parser("Users.csv");
            DisplayUsersInAD(userParser.Parse());

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static void DisplayUsersNotInAD(user[] list)
        {
            ADLookup lookup = new ADLookup();
            foreach (User u in list)
                if (lookup.IsUserInAD(u.login) == true)
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} was found in AD.", u.login);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What part of the message don't you understand?

Comment: Does `User` exist in the namespace `verifyUsers` (apparently not)? The error message is pretty straight forward.

Comment: Type `user` with a lowercase u, not `User` (`foreach (user u in list)`). If it is a class, then rename the class to `User` to follow naming conventions.

Comment: Be gentle this is all VERY new to me. Spent most of my career in hardware, but you adapt if you want to keep a job in this market :)

Comment: How can I verify if User is in the namespace verifyUsers

Comment: made the change to lowercase user, same issue

Comment: If in Visual Studio, try putting the caret on User and typing Ctrl-. that should give you the namespace to add that contains User - assuming its referenced by your project. I would wonder where ADLookup is defined ??

Comment: I have ADLookup.cs with using system.DirectoryServices; system.directoryservices is referenced also

Answer (score 3):

Watch your casing!

You are using `User` and `user`. Which one is correct?

**EDIT**

If that was not the problem, find the project or DLL's where the `User` should be in. Make sure you have a reference from your project to the other project or DLL (via: right click on `References` and choose `Add reference...`.)

If you are sure you have the correct reference, right click on the `user` and choose `Resolve...` to add the correct namespace.

Another problem could be that the `User` is part of your project. Make sure that file is included in your project. If so, right click on the file and make sure that `Build Action` is set to `Compile`.

Comment: Good catch... didnt notice that

Comment: I made the change to foreach (user u in list) and still get the error

Comment: Do you know where that user should exists? Is it in one of your own projects? Is it in a third party library?

Comment: should i have user.cs also in my project? I am using fileHelpers which is a .net library and it is referenced also

Comment: I am sorry... you should know where `User` is located. No one else here can know that. If you have found it, let us know, so we can help you refer it in the correct way.

Answer (score 1):

I am thinking that the namespace of User and the current class is different, please check it.
If so import it like `using <UserNamespace>` or make the namespace the same.
The other thing is in the static method

```
static void DisplayUsersNotInAD(user[] list)
        {
            ADLookup lookup = new ADLookup();
            foreach (User u in list)
                if (lookup.IsUserInAD(u.login) == true)
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} was found in AD.", u.login);
        }
```

the parameter user and the object u may are not the same since User is not the same with user(with lower case). check also this.

hope this help you.

Answer (score -1):

This is not realy an answer to your question but since you are new to programming in C# one suggestion:

In C# it is common practice to camel case class names. So, in your code parser should be Parser

```
Parser userParser = new Parser("Users.csv");
```

and user should be User

```
static void DisplayUsersNotInAD(User[] list)
```

Good luck and happy coding!

Comment: -1 This is called Pascal casing not camel casing. Pascal casing: "Parser" and "UserParser". Camel casing: "parser" and "userParser".